# literal string vs variable string

Tags: r

I want to load a dataset using the data() function. The name of the dataset is obtained from another function. 
So I want to do the following:

```
var1 <- "mydataset"
data(var1)
```

However, it says that there is not a dataset with var1 as name!

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data(list=var1)
```

Since `data` tries to be helpful and allow for an unquoted name to be specified, you need to be explicit and pass the character vector as the `list` argument.